# Intersection observer for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use intersection observer in my project and I want to use jquery how intersection observer works in jQuery. I tried to pass jQuery element in the observe function but it didn't work.

```
const aboutUsObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
            $(".active").removeClass("underlined");
            $("#aboutUsNavItem").toggleClass("underlined");
        } else {
            $(".active").removeClass("underlined");
        }
    });
}, {});

aboutUsObserver.observe($("#about-us-section"));
```

Comment: You are missing either a `#` or `.` in `$("aboutUsNavItem")`

Comment: I have added it in the question, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [pass an actual element when calling `observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe), and not a jQuery object. You can access the underlying element of a jQuery object by using `.get()` or `[0]`:

```
// Option 1:
aboutUsObserver.observe($("#about-us-section").get());

// Option 2:
aboutUsObserver.observe($("#about-us-section")[0]);
```

Even better: do you *really* need jQuery tho?

```
// Use document.querySelector
aboutUsObserver.observe(document.querySelector("#about-us-section"));

// Or use document.getElementById
aboutUsObserver.observe(document.getElementById("about-us-section"));
```

Comment: Thanks you, helped me a lot 

Comment: @mohammadyahyaq Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add [0] to the end of selector.

```js
const aboutUsObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log("Here!")
            $(".active").removeClass("underlined");
            $("#aboutUsNavItem").toggleClass("underlined");
        } else {
            $(".active").removeClass("underlined");
        }
    });
}, {});

aboutUsObserver.observe($("#about-us-section")[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about-us-section" style="position:absolute; top:1000px">test</div>
```